# Visa transit from Auckland to Dubai

Tags: customs-and-immigration, vietnamese-citizens

Do I need to have visa transit when i am flying from Auckland to Dubai. I will just stay in the airport and not leave airport. I am Vietnamese as well

Comment: Are you speaking about a transit visa for New Zealand or for the UAE?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please [edit] your post as it is unclear: what airports are you flying to and from, and via which other airport?

Comment: It is not clear what is your itinerary. Where are you flying and where do you intend to transit?